# Detect long code lines in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just ran across this terrible code:

```
string summary = Controls.BasePage1.GetLDA().ExecuteStringScalar(sb).Replace("'", "\\'");
```

It's not doing adequate null checks.  Is there any way to detect long lines of code like this in a Visual Studio project?

Comment: Do you want to detect long lines or possible null reference exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Plain vanilla Visual Studio doesn't support search for long lines nor `NullReferenceException` checks.

There is an option to wrap long lines but it doesn't break lines to smaller units. (Tools -> Options... -> Text editor -> C# -> General -> Word wrap). If you widen your visual studio instance it will unwrap the line.

However, the functionality you are looking for is provided by third party plug-ins. I'm using ReSharper. It can find any possible `NullReferenceException`s in your code. Also it can automatically format your lines to whatever length you prefer. (Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping has quite a few options to fine tune code editing.)